# Excel Formula to shift value of Column A and B to C and D empty cells

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

I have an excel data (Genes) like,
[Excel Screen Shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOcit.png)

I need to move value in column A and B to Column C and D Empty cells Like,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0ASw.png)

Please suggest any formula.

Comment: Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72800372/fill-blank-cell-in-column … and also here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 0):

Working with just the 4 columns you will get a self-referencing problem. You have to work with col E and F

so in E2
if(C2<>"",C2,A2)
similar in F2....